# Detecting core data relationship change in a NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a Person entity that has a bunch of too-many relationships. I have a category on Person and I wanted to have a way to change an attribute on person in case any of the too-many realtionships are changed in any way.

What is the best way of accomplishing this?

simple scenario would be adding new entities to the toomany realtionships like so:

```
MORE DETAILS: 
P<-->> cars
P<-->> friends

If p is a person object:
car.p = p;
friend.p = p;
```

Thank you

Comment: can you be more specific regarding how the 1-n relationship is going to change?

Answer (score 0):

zumzum,

The main way to track such changes is to use key-value observing (KVO) on each of your to-many relationships.

Apple's documentation on KVO is complete and straightforward. There are also many tutorials a Google-away.

Andrew